# Why is it compiled? - T = Supplier<T>?

Tags: java, functional-interface, supplier

I have an 'Animal' interface and 'Dog' class that implements 'Animal'.

```
public interface Animal {
    void makeVoice();
}
```

```
public class Dog implements Animal {
    @Override
    public void makeVoice() {
        System.out.println("aou aou");
    }
}
```

In my main method, I wrote the following lines.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal dog = Dog::new; // How is it compiled? it should be Supplier<Animal>

        dog.makeVoice(); // Doesn't call because 'dog' holds lambda expression (Supplier<Animal>) and not the actual 'Dog' class.
    }
}
```

Why is it possible that Animal can hold Supplier?

I expected that it doesn't compile.

Comment: Your `Animal` interface is a valid functional interface, so you can assign `Dog::new` to a variable of that type, just like if it were `Supplier`, `Runnable` or any other functional interface that doesn't take arguments (because `Dog::new` is "void-compatible", it doesn't matter if it has a return type or void). If you add another method to the interface, it won't be a functional interface anymore.

Comment: BTW: the variable `dog` doesn't hold a `Supplier<Animal>`, it holds an `Animal` (specifically a lambda that will execute `new Dog()` when you call `makeVoice()`).

Comment: when I call makeVoice(), nothing happens..

Comment: Create the no argument constructor for Dog and add a print statement. You will see it execute when calling makeVoice.

Comment: I think that I understand. 'Animal' has "makeVoice()" that it is feet to "Dog::new" signature, so every time I call "makeVoice()" I actually run "() -> new Dog()". Thanks for all!

Comment: If it helps, imagine you've made some kind of monster animal that, when it opens its mouth, spits out a dog instead of making a sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor for `Dog` satisfies the `Animal` functional interface. The parameter types match as both `makeVoice` and the default constructor for `Dog` take no parameters. The constructor call is also void-compatible (it matches the `void` return type) because a class instance creation expression is an [expression statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8).

The code is essentially equivalent to the following and it creates an implementation of `Animal`, not `Supplier`:

```java
Animal dog = () -> new Dog();
// or equivalently, as the created Dog instance is ignored:
Animal dog = () -> {
    new Dog();
};
```

As an anonymous class, it would look like this:

```java
Animal dog = new Animal() {
    @Override
    public void makeVoice() {
        new Dog();
    }
};
```

Comment: dog hold Supplier. please check again.
Supplier<Animal> dogSupplier = () -> new Dog();

Comment: @MaorHassid No, that's not how it works. You can use the same lambda or method reference to implement multiple different functional interfaces, as long as the signature is compatible. You set the type to Animal, so it isn't a Supplier.

Comment: @MaorHassid easy to test, a `Supplier` declares a `get()` method, try `dog.get()`

Comment: How can you explain that 'dog.makeVoice()' doesn't work?

Comment: @MaorHassid when calling `makeVoice()`, from the interface `Animal`¹, it will do `new Dog()`, that is, create an instance of `Dog` which will then be lost, since `makeVoice()` is declared to return `void`... add `System.out.println(...)` to the constructor of `Dog` to verify that. || **¹** it is NOT calling `makeVoice()` from `Dog`